Drones are designed with lightweight materials to reduce weight. - is the subject of the infinitive clause "drones"?
Example 1

Drones are designed with lightweight materials to reduce weight.

What is the subject of the to-infinitive clause "to reduce weight"?
If my memories serve me right, the subject of a to-infinitive clause, if not mentioned, should be the same one as the subject of the sentence.
So we can rewrite it as:

Drones are designed with lightweight materials for them to reduce weight.

So, in this case, is the subject of the to-infinitive "Drones," same as the subject of the sentence? However, it is kind of saying that drones are the ones that reduce their own weights,  which sounds wierd.
An example that the subject of to-infinitive phrase is clearly the same as the subject of the sentence.
Like this one:

Drones are designed with cameras to assist people in filming videos.

It clearly says

Drones are designed with cameras for them to assist people in filming videos.


No. Drones don't reduce weight, their design does. They are designed that way. They are not that way. The infinitive shows how they are designed, so it modified the verb.

Drones are designed with lightweight materials to reduce weight -why do you need the last three words?

"the subject of a to-infinitive clause, if not mentioned, should be the same one as the subject of the sentence." That's not right, although it might work in some situations. "He bought the chicken to lay eggs for him" is fine. But it's not always quite clear what the to-infinitive is modifying.

Does this answer your question? How do you call the subject of infinitive clause?

As mentioned in the comments, you have been told something incorrect. While it is sometimes true that "the subject of a to-infinitive clause, if not mentioned, should be the same one as the subject of the sentence.", it is not always the case.
In this instance, your instincts are correct and it doesn't make sense to say that drones reduce their own weight. As Yosef pointed out, the design is the actor in this phrase since the design reduces the weight.
This feels odd to think about, since design is not a noun in this sentence, rather a past tense verb. But it's the closest thing we can come to a subject.
